# Installing chef-dk & Inspec on Solaris

Tags: chef-infra, solaris, inspec, chefdk

How do I install Chef-DK and Inspec on Solaris?

I have Chef-Client (Version 14.5.33) installed on my Solaris machine.

I tried executing: `curl https://omnitruck.chef.io/install.sh | sudo bash -s -- -P inspec` and `curl https://omnitruck.chef.io/install.sh | sudo bash -s -- -P chef-dk` and I get following error:

```
> solaris2 5.11 i386 Getting information for inspec stable  for
> solaris2... downloading
> https://omnitruck.chef.io/stable/inspec/metadata?v=&p=solaris2&pv=5.11&m=i386
> to file /tmp/install.sh.3129/metadata.txt trying wget... ERROR 404
> Omnitruck artifact does not exist for version  on platform solaris2
> 
> Either this means:
>    - We do not support solaris2
>    - We do not have an artifact for 
> 
> This is often the latter case due to running a prerelease or RC
> version of chef or a gem version which was only pushed to rubygems and
> not omnitruck.
> 
> You may be able to set your knife[:bootstrap_version] to the most
> recent stable release of Chef to fix this problem (or the most recent
> stable major version number).
> 
> In order to test the version parameter, adventurous users may take the
> Metadata URL below and modify the '&v=<number>' parameter until you
> successfully get a URL that does not 404 (e.g. via curl or wget).  You
> should be able to use '&v=11' or '&v=12' succesfully.
> 
> If you cannot fix this problem by setting the bootstrap_version, it
> probably means that solaris2 is not supported.
> 
> Metadata URL:
> https://omnitruck.chef.io/stable/inspec/metadata?v=&p=solaris2&pv=5.11&m=i386
```

Comment: Possibly relevant:  https://github.com/oracle/solaris-chef-cookbook/blob/master/README.md